# What are the de facto advantages of Sweden and Finland joining NATO?

Tags: nato, sweden, finland

There is [a plethora of news](https://www.google.com/search?q=sweden%20and%20finland%20nato%20opposed%20by%20turkey) about Turkey opposing Sweden and Finland from joining NATO, suggesting that this will be quite a long process.

Being part of NATO offers an important advantage (besides others) due to collective defense ([article 5](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_110496.htm)), but I am interested mostly in the de facto advantages here based on the following rationale:

- NATO [successfully rolled out arms in Ukraine](https://foreignpolicy.com/2022/04/15/tanks-heavy-weapons-ukraine-russia-nato-putin-offensive/), a non-NATO member, which had an important role in pushing back the invading Russian army
- Both [Sweden](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_52535.htm) and [Finland](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_49594.htm)'s armies ensure interoperable capabilities with NATO, so I guess NATO helping them would be even easier than in Ukraine's case

That means that NATO (+ others interested to help) can effectively help a country resist a Russian invasion regardless of NATO membership.

Is there anything on the practical side that brings NATO membership for Sweden and Finland on the short-medium term (1-2 years)?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71080/what-could-russia-do-against-finland-and-sweden-if-they-join-nato

Comment: Well, it means that Russia is less likely to invade them in the near future.

Comment: @RedSonja Judging by the progress in Ukraine, I do not think they will be able to invade another country anytime soon.

Comment: @Alexei the brave and intrepid Ukrainians are keeping us safe *for the time being*

Comment: Advantages for whom?  NATO or Sweden/Finland?  Both?

Comment: @RedSonja even during the Cold War Russia (USSR) never tried to invade that countries.

Comment: @convert - Which country? If Ukraine, the Soviet Union obviously did not invade it, because it was part of the Soviet Union. If Finland, it invaded it shortly before the Cold War (the Winter War).

Comment: @Obie 2.0 I was expecting such answer, that´s why I was tallking about the period of the Cold War. I am not deniing Winter War, but there were also some strategic goals for USSR in that war, in first place remove a border of a hostile country from Stpetersburg.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Or advantages for Russia…?

Comment: I'm curious if NATO rolled out arms, or if individual countries (which happen to be members of NATO) did? Does it really matter, and is anyone paying attention to the details?

Comment: @gerrit indeed. I've wondered whether pushing Finland and Sweden to join NATO is Putin playing a 'long game'. I don't know what the end goal would be, if that was the case, though. Drag the world into a new war? I don't know..

Comment: @Alexei Advantages for whom?

Comment: @user795826 For Finland and Sweden, mostly.

Comment: If you want to base anything on a plethora of news about Turkey opposing Sweden and Finland from joining NATO, suggesting anything, why not drop that pure speculation?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a difference between providing arms and **going to war**. You are correct that under the current status quo, if Russia seriously threatened Sweden or Finland, NATO nations would unquestionably provide them with military aid. But the full extent of that aid and the form it takes would be a matter of debate.

But NATO membership means that [an attack on one is an attack on all](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natolive/official_texts_17120.htm). Finland joining NATO would mean that a Russian attack on Finland would be considered an attack on the United States, an attack on the UK, an attack on France. That is to say, a Russian invasion would be a de facto declaration of war on the entirety of NATO.

Right now NATO is in something of a proxy war with Russia. If Ukraine had been in NATO, there would be no "proxy" about it, it'd just mean the full might of the UK, France, Germany, and US coming down on Russia. At absolute worst, it'd mean nuclear exchange, end of the world, that whole business.

If that sounds like something Russia would never, ever do, you're probably correct. And Finland and Sweden are hoping the same.

**tl;dr- NATO membership is the difference between generous military support in the face of invasion, and a near-guarantee the invasion will never happen in the first place**

Comment: Even without NATO membership, an attack on Finland would be an attack on France and Germany. Not US and UK, however, and Russia seems to take *only* the US seriously.

Comment: @o.m. can you elaborate why an attack on Finland would also be an attack on France and Germany? Is there any contract?

Comment: @o.m. If you allude to the EU memberhip of Finland and Sweden, the EU clauses are *much* weaker than NATOs. Germany could say we send "thoughts and prayers" and we'd fulfil the EU obligations.

Comment: @Polygnome can you be more specific?  *Article 42 (7) TEU states:

If a Member State is the victim of armed aggression on its territory, the other Member States shall have towards it an obligation of aid and assistance by all the means in their power, in accordance with Article 51 of the United Nations Charter.* in the [relevant EU treaty](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-7390/) does not seem all that obviously weaker than article 5 which stops well short of *forcing* military action.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica " This shall not prejudice the specific character of the security and defence policy of certain Member States.". This sentence pretty much completely undermines it. If any member states thinks that "thoughts and prayers" is all they can do, so be it.

Comment: @Polygnome I'll raise you an [article 5](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natolive/official_texts_17120.htm) :  *,such action as it deems necessary, including the use of armed force,* ;-)  Thoughts and prayers to you too.  Besides it's odd to make such a big deal of the exact wording when there is such an overlap in membership.  Are you claiming Germany is going to be a NATO lion but an EU weasel?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica "an armed attack against one [...] shall be considered an attack against them all" **is** a much stronger commitment. If you have any doubt about what article V is and what it isn't (and what article 42 TEU is and isn't), please read up on some actual legal expert opinions on that topic. Your own source states " it does not go so far as to confer a security commitment, akin to NATO's Article V". And also look into the history of Article 42 TEU and why it is stated that way and specifically, what it was designed *not* to be.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The EU was designed as *economic* entity, having evolved from the ECSC and then having absorbed some other institutions. It is only slowing understanding that it also *needs* to be a more political entity (a process which was started with the "modern" EU) and also a *military* entity. It was never designed to be a military alliance. If I was Finland or Sweden, I wouldn't count on any EU member bailing me out. NATO and EU are two vastly different beasts with vastly different goals.

Comment: We'll agree to disagree.  You claim the treaties are inherently different.  Their exact wording is not all that dissimilar, including opt-out clauses.  At the end of the day, each country, whether it is acting as an EU member or a NATO member will act as it sees in its best interest:  following the spirit of the treaty - mutual defense - if it feels forced to by circumstances, invoking some legalese opt out if it wants to shirk those responsibilities.  The wording is similar in both cases and I only picked that link for the full text.  Remember the UK has long been dubious on EU military.

Comment: @Polygnome, the key difference between the EU and NATO promises is that NATO has planned and rehearsed. Much easier to say "we'll activate whatever Eagle Guardian is now" than "hmm, what can we do."

Comment: @o.m. Actually, the [UK has a mutual defense pact with Finland, and with Sweden](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-61408700), announced last month.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica What you say (about nations having to determine for themselves their individual responses in any crisis) is very valid, however, the outcome of a member nation NOT following the treaties is/could be considerably different. If Russia were to attack Poland tomorrow and if the GB decided to send its 'best wishes'... the chances of NATO dissolving would be much more than nil.

Comment: 'If that sounds like something Russia would never, ever do, you're probably correct.' -- the last 10 or so years have somehow managed to destroy all remaining confidence I had in 'by common sense they would never do THAT' (apply to all *they*'s, explicitly *not* just Russia).

Comment: Notwithstanding the potential differences between the defense treaty of the EU and NATO, having access  to *both* likely helps - as if one of them falters, there's always the possibility of relying on the other treaty. Like, if the U.K. didn't support Belgium during WWI, but they had a separate treaty with France as well, they'd *still* jump in, just later than they officially declared in WWI against Germany's attempted invasion of France through Belgium.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: Related re: what exactly NATO article 5 requires / supports: [Would a (nuclear) strike that hits an NATO member state embassy/extraterritoriality in Ukraine be considered a (nuclear) strike against NATO?](//politics.stackexchange.com/q/71759)  It's not *automatic* declaration of war, so perhaps it matters a lot how it's interpreted by the nations involved.  Potential aggressors know that NATO members are prepared to fully go to war in case of a deliberate attack that can't be diplomatically explained away as a mistake.  This is related to o.m.'s point re: exercises

Comment: *it'd just mean the full might of the UK, France, Germany, and US coming down on Russia* => in theory yes but in practice we don't know if the US would've nuked Moscow if it tried to attack, say, Latvia.

Answer (score 19):

It's probably more a political gain *in clarity* than a straight out military gain.

First, let's start out that neither Finland nor Sweden are like Ukraine.
They are long time Western-aligned, rather than Ukraine's unfortunate and not very voluntary membership in what Russia considers its near-abroad club.  They are also EU members, which brings in formal mutual defense guarantees, again unlike Ukraine.  And they have very little in the way of Russian sympathizers to stir up trouble to justify "assisting ethnic brothers" with.  Last, the Nordics generally look out for each other and Norway and Denmark, NATO founding members both, would bring extra pressure to assist them.

**So, even in the absence of NATO membership, Russia would be foolish to *assume* that it could pull a Georgia(South Ossetia) / Moldova(Transnistria) / Ukraine(Crimea) on them and not get the West involved (remember many EU members are also in NATO).**

Both countries found it best not to get too lined up with NATO during the Cold War.  Finland was treaty-bound not to do so in any case, but their reality is that are rather near Russia and NATO in the 70s and 80s would have been stretched to win a conventional war in Germany/northern Europe, let alone assisting Finland at the end of the Baltic Sea.

Forward to the 90s and it didn't seem necessary to antagonize Russia.  Sure, NATO was now dominant, but Russia could be lived alongside with.  That was the popular belief in Finland against joining NATO.

Militarily?  Both countries have good armies, certainly, but they are also quite unsuitable to attack Russia.  Integrating them is easy, using them to "win" against Russia would not be:

- Finland: small core army of professionals (15K?) with a massive conscription-based system that can bring it up to 280K on short notice.  This is an army geared towards **defense** in depth, trading space for attacker attrition.
- Sweden: 50k professionals-based army, with a small, 4k, conscripts call-up per year.

Again, operating from Finland, which can easily threaten St. Petersburg, means ferrying in troops through the Baltic, past Kaliningrad.

Russia, *if it analyzes the military risks logically*, will not be thrilled, but is not at any great risk of surprise assault.  *Then again, the US, with Cuba, shows how antsy a big power can be about having unfriendly neighbors.*

So there is some gain, but also a heightened risk of confrontation with Russia along that now front-line 1300km long border.  On the other hand, Russia is busy aggressing Ukraine right now so won't have much to be aggressive with in the short term.  By the time it's recovered it will be in the same straightjacket attacking those 2 as NATO is in Ukraine:  nuclear weapons make bloc-on-bloc direct combat suicidal and NATO's conventional forces can trounce Russia's.

Yes, there is undoubtedly more risk of confrontation on a longer, more sensitive border.  But there is also a benefit to bring clarity and stop the temptation for partway adventurism by Russia that could escalate.  NATO is on the hook formally, rather than being dragged in accidentally if Russia miscalculates.

**For all parties involved, Finland and Sweden will become de-facto untouchable rather than something that needs to be thought about.  Both countries' traditionally neutral-ish electorates have come to the conclusion that there is little to be gained by not antagonizing Russia, not because there is nobility in joining a military pact, but because Putin's Russia fundamentally can't be trusted.**

p.s. the fact that they are both joining together is not a coincidence.  They apparently have had a long standing agreement to take the jump together or not at all.

Comment: Based on what I've got from the Finnish media, I haven't had the impression that there'd been a _agreement_ for joining together as such. Not before it now actually started to happen, anyway. Just an understanding of the reality that Finland joining with Sweden staying out would be somewhat awkward because of the geography, and it would be much easier e.g. to supply Finland from the West if crossing Sweden was part of the plans. And on the other hand, Sweden joining and Finland staying out would leave Finland _very_ alone sitting next to Russia.

Comment: Hmmm, I am pretty sure I've seen somewhere that this is a *previous* actual agreement/understanding between the 2.  It wasn't for joining together *now*, it was for coordinating accession, either to keep out or to get in.  So it may not be very easy to find in current media, but there are hints about it all over NATO accession discussions pre-2022 *and* the 2 are always discussed together.  Will look around.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Finland had declared a NATO-option, Sweden hadn't.

Comment: Nice answer, but about *They are long time Western-aligned*... well, for Finland it is way more complicated than that.

Comment: *NATO in the 70s and 80s would have been stretched to win a conventional war in Germany/northern Europe* — are you sure?  I thought that the US had always been militarily far dominant over the Soviet Union in conventional military terms.

Comment: Why would operating from Finland mean ferrying troops past Kaliningrad? If Sweden had also joined then that would be moot altogether, a perfectly fine land-path existed. But even in the absence of Sweden, the option of going via the northern coast of Norway exists.

Comment: @Jan because the Norway route is not the most hospitable logistical chain to attack Russia with.  There's pretty much nothing up there, except for Murmansk - which can threaten NATO ships.  In WW2, this was nowhere as active as southern Finland.  Re. Sweden, trains have nowhere near the lift capability of ships.  I am not saying none can be used, only that none of the 3 are all that great to attack Russia by.  Bit of a disclaimer:  in 1941, 3.5K German tanks punched through 20K Soviets so Russia may not feel so relaxed about local enemy capabilities, in either actual belief or propaganda.

Comment: Hasn't Sweden restarted conscription over the last few years? It was a rather short stretch where they had none at all.

Comment: @gormadoc good catch.  one part of wikipedia gets it right, the other doesn't.  updated answer.

Comment: @gerrit , in the 70's and early 80's, US tank doctrine & material was behind the USSR. It wasn't until the Abrams was rolled out and the tank doctrine was updated that USA started to gain equality on the battlefield. The result of these changes were shown in the success of Dessert Storm.

Comment: @gerrit  About 4 months back I had another hi-rep user chip in the exact opposite:  "but the Soviets would have wiped NATO".  Truth is, we don't know.  The Warsaw Pact had massive numbers and NATO's superiority in electronics and miniaturization didn't count as much on older tanks/jets/etc.  But... logistics?  motivation of Polish/Hungarian/Czech troops to fight for Russia?  Really, who knows?  Soviet battle doctrine called for tac-nukes-fronted deep penetration so they weren't convinced it was going to be a walk in the park themselves.  But a lot of ppl doubted NATO could win conventionally.

Answer (score 12):

> That means that NATO (+ others interested to help) can effectively help a country resist a Russian invasion regardless of NATO membership.

It's not the same. The help that Ukraine received was rather small compared to what one could expect if Ukraine would have been a member of NATO. The war in Ukraine would certainly have looked very much different. I even guess that it would have never taken place at all. That is a very big difference.

Being a member of NATO is still way better than only being some third country, which is lucky to receive some help, in terms of security assurances.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some long term advantages for Russia as well.

Russia needs to invade a neighboring country once in a while (likely once in a president term) in order to maintain its "power process".

If left out of available neigbors for invasion, the economy may take over the decision-making that is now dominated by police and military people.

It may as well (one can only hope) slowly turn into liberal democracy.

Or, at least, turn into a much safer economy-centered dictatorship like e.g. China (instead of the military-centered dictatorship it is now).

Comment: This is interesting, but *very* speculative.  Could you back it up with some sources?

Comment: This is an answer to "What is the de facto advantage for Russia if more countries would be NATO members?", which is not this question here unfortunately.

Comment: @Trilarion I'd say gradually nudging Russia towards abandoning its "wannabe superpower" politics is good for Europe or the NATO in general, Sweden and Finland included.

Comment: @gerrit Well, the past few decades provide multiple well-known examples of Russian invasions of neighbouring countries without a real reason apart from having something to show to the domestic audience. The rest is indeed just speculation (or perhaps wishful thinking).

Comment: @Trilarion The question does not specify advantages for *whom*.

Comment: The Russian military has very little influence. Power in Russia comes from Putin and from extraction industries (oil and gas mostly), the military is not allowed to become influential in order to prevent any risk of a coup.